# How to sum these volumes, per group?

Tags: spotfire, spotfire-analyst

i am working with spotfire and i need some help. I am trying to sum these volumes for each lot but since i have more than one row for each lot, it is summing all the volumes (which is wrong, i only want to add a single value of volume).
How can i do this?

[my cross table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MACrR.png)

I am still new to this, so i am trying to use custom expressions like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owBHQ.png)

but its resulting this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SkVd.png)

but since i only have 2 groups, there should be only 2 volumes per group